# A .Net Exception being caught on a thread with no .Net code

Tags: .net, multithreading, exception, visual-c++, clr

I have a field report showing a .Net exception getting caught in a non .Net  thread.

Is it possible that a non-.Net thread is somehow picking up an exception coming from a CLR thread somewhere else?

Here's what I'm seeing in the log:

```
.Net Exception caught in real time processing
External component has thrown an exception.
at CFileMaster.CheckRuleForIsInteresting(...)
at CFileMaster.RealTimeIsInterestingCheck(...)
at CDLP.RealTimeIsInterestingCheck(...)
at CFileMaster.RealTimeProcessingCheck(...)
at CFileMaster.RealTimeProcessing(...)
at CIFSHandler.WorkerThread(...)
```

Here's what the try/catch looks like:

```
try
{
  pThis->RealTimeProcessing(pFileRequest, bDenyAccess, bShouldDelete, bRedirect, sRedirectTo, bIsInteresting);
}
catch (CException* e)
{
  traceLog.WriteError(L"CException caught in real time processing");
  <snip>
}
catch(Exception^ ne)
{
  traceLog.WriteError(L".Net Exception caught in real time processing");
  traceLog.WriteError(ne->Message);
  traceLog.WriteError(ne->StackTrace);
  continue;
}
catch(...)
{
   <snip>
}
```

the RealTimeProcessing method is string old school C++ code.  No .Net calls anywhere.

I have NO idea how to approach this since I can't reproduce it.

This is happening on a 24 Core application server with 8 GB of memory...maybe I'm running out of memory?

Comment: I would more thoroughly log the exception, particularly take note of all inner exceptions. I'd be rather surprised if there wasn't one considering the error message

Comment: It might be the CLR that detects an error while running your C++ code and raises that as a .NET exception. As @Voo suggests, try printing inner exceptions. At the very least output the exact exception type (GetType().ToString()).

Comment: While I still don't understand why I'm getting a .net exception, I was corrupting non-managed memory by non-managed code).  I was able to track down the problem and get it fixed.  thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0):

This is [C++/CLI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C%2B%2B/CLI) code. This language enables you to write *mixed* code. That is both native as well as managed code in the same source code file. You can use both native types and as well as types from the .NET Framework class library (FCL). You can also catch managed exceptions as well as C++ exceptions. In particular, this catch block

```
catch(Exception^ ne)
{
  traceLog.WriteError(L".Net Exception caught in real time processing");
  traceLog.WriteError(ne->Message);
  traceLog.WriteError(ne->StackTrace);
  continue;
}
```

is catching any managed exception (**Exception^** is equivalent to **Exception** in C#). This is the block that is catching the exception your are experiencing.

On the other hand, the previous catch block is activated for native exceptions derived from **CException** which is the base type of all exceptions in the Microsoft Foundation Class (MFC) library.